# I got the error like No Activity found to handle Intent even i introduced it in manifest.xml properly

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Here is my code for login page and im getting the error of no actvity to handle this intent

this is my java file of background worker through which
i want to call the next activity name

```
package com.example.pritam.myapplication;

/**
 * Created by Pritam on 3/17/2016.
 */

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
      Context context;


          AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
            BackgroundWorker (Context ctx) {
                context = ctx;
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground (String...params){
                String result = "";
                String login_url = "http://192.168.1.102/login.php";
                try {
                    String uname = params[0];
                    String pass = params[1];
                    URL url = new URL(login_url);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream out = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("uname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(uname, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    out.close();
                    InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "iso-8859-1"));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result += line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    in.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                /*   if (result.equals("Login Successfull")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("BackgroundWorker.this,function.class");
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }*/
                //httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
                //return result;


            }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Login Status");


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           /* if (result.equals("Login Successfull")) {
                Intent intent;
                intent = new Intent(context,function.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }*/

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            context.startActivity( new Intent("BackgroundWorker.this,function.class"));

                        }
                    }
            );
                    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
         //  if (result.equals("Login Successfull")) {
//                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                    /*@Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        context.startActivity( new Intent("BackgroundWorker.this,function.class"));

                    }*/

                //Intent intent = new Intent("BackgroundWorker.this,function.class");
                //context.startActivity(intent);


        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

    }


    My Manifest.xml file
```

I have included the correct activity in manifest also but getting the same error while running it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pritam.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".function"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <action android:name="com.example.pritam.myapplication.function" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>



    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am certain this line of code is not at all what you meant:

```
context.startActivity( new Intent("BackgroundWorker.this,function.class"));
```

You're creating an Intent with a single string argument.  Try something else more like this:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, function.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

context.startActivity(new Intent("BackgroundWorker.this,function.class"));

In above statement you use **BackgroundWorker.this** is a class

if you want to call the next activity. Then you must give the context of application.

Correct statement is like this

**context.startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),function.class"));**